# Includes: SSI or PHP for basic HTML and Javascript in separate files

Tags: php, javascript, file, include, ssi

I got my Xampp server running and can run my html in subdirectories now, as well (can't have spaces in the subdirectory names).

**SSI Includes or PHP Includes:**

Xampp says SSI is deactivated. Tried uncommenting the lines for includes, but it doesn't change the deactivation.

How do I activate SSI?

Then, how do I implement either SSI include statements or PHP include statements into my html to call up html files that include html, images, javascript and commands that call other javascript menu files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Xampp has a special way of activating SSI or not, but the [normal Apache way](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html#configuring) should work.

The normal way to include files in SSI is

```
<!--#include virtual="/something/file.html" -->
```

where the url to the file is actually http://www.example.com/something/file.html .

Answer (score 0):

PHP includes are pretty straightforward.  Just name your file something.php and do this:

```
<?php include('path/to/file.php'); ?>
```

The file will be parsed by php so it can contain the standard mix of PHP/HTML tags or whatever other text you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If XAMPP says SSI are disabled by default, you need to edit your server configuration (**not your .HTACCESS file**) to change this. *Otherwise, you could try installing a plugin for your server to fix the issue.*

Hope this helps!

*~ Nate.*